# Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web vs Web Matrix

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012, typescript, webmatrix

What's the difference Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web and Web Matrix. I need support of NodeJS and TypeScript. I would love to know about free software like the above and also best way to develop website using 2-3 laptops.

Our group have 3 laptops and wand to develop simultaneously on website development. We want to have LAN connection using Wi-Fi hot spot and connect to a NodeJS server. Update in any files will update the server automatically using Hotnode or Nodemon.

I want to change IDE like Sublime to VS Express 2012 Web which is free so that I can take advantage of TypeScript better and cumulative web development.

So, Plz suggest your opinion on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is typeScript + nodejs , the IDE I would recommend is WebStorm by JetBrains. It has the best NodeJs support in the market. And you can use it to debug TypeScript on the front end (browser) as well as backend (node)

Comment: Is JetBrains free or I have to pay price.

Comment: It costs 50 dollars for individuals. 29$ for students.